# Объединение данных из двух таблиц в запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT a.*
   FROM tableA a
   // ...
   WHERE atr_a = 1 AND atr_b = 2
```

В таблице tableA есть поле t_id - это поле, которое содержит в себе ID из таблице tableB.

В таблице tebleB есть поле user_id.

Вопрос: что добавить в запрос, чтобы вернулись строки из tableA, в которых заполнен id в поле t_id (например 1), а в tableB, поле user_id равно значению t_id из tableA (например 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте JOIN. Ваш запрос будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
SELECT *
    FROM tableA a
    JOIN tableB b ON a.t_id = b.user_id
    WHERE atr_a = 1 AND atr_b = 2
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]